# How do I Change HyperlinkButtons' image according to the page that is currently displayed

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml

I have a bunch (currently) HyperlinkButtons on my main web page. I want to have 2 versions for the image of each button: selected and unselected. This way when the users enters a page the corresponding button will change to the "selected" image. 
Here is an image of what I want to accomplish:
[image]

This seems to me like something trivial, but so far I have been running into a stone wall.
I would prefer to do everything from the XAML (but I will be grateful for any solution).

Here is a little of my XAML:

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="NavScrollViewer" Margin="-5,12,5,-12" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" IsEnabled="True" 
                  Style="{StaticResource ContentViewerStyle}">
            <StackPanel x:Name="ToolboxPanel" Orientation="Vertical" d:LayoutOverrides="Width" Height="Auto">

                <HyperlinkButton x:Name="DashboardButton"
                    Content="Assets/icon_dashboard.png" 
                    Style="{StaticResource ToolStyle}"
                    TargetName="ContentFrame"
                    NavigateUri="/Dashboard"
                    Height="50"
                />
                <TextBlock Text="Dashboard" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="20" Style="{StaticResource ComponentNameStyle}"/>

                <HyperlinkButton x:Name="ConfigurationButton"
                    Content="Assets/icon_dashboard.png" 
                    Style="{StaticResource ToolStyle}"
                    TargetName="ContentFrame"
                    NavigateUri="/CRSConfiguration"
                    Height="50"
                />
                <TextBlock Text="Configuration" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="20" Style="{StaticResource ComponentNameStyle}"/>
                    <HyperlinkButton x:Name="ScanEnginestionButton"
                    Content="Assets/icon_dashboard.png" 
                    Style="{StaticResource ToolStyle}"
                    TargetName="ContentFrame"
                    NavigateUri="/ScanEngines"
                    Height="50"
                />...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have a toggle button and set its IsChecked property to toggle among its visual states. You may go through this post [Using Toggle Button](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/f78da620-2e70-4eb2-bd8e-838f58d498a5)